# Keyboard Setting for Moving Windows to Different Workspaces in Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, dconf

Is there a GNOME/DCONF setting to set a keybind for moving windows to different workspaces?

The desired behavior would be to press Super+Shift+3 (or whatever shortcut I specify), and have the both my view and the focused window moved to workspace 3.